# Discharge of a script after a AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I write a ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    //dataType: "json", //type of data
    crossDomain: true, //localhost purposes
    url: "./query/ins_desc.php", //Relative or absolute path to file.php file
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(response));
        var instructor = JSON.parse(response);
        var el = "";
        i = i - 1;
        el += "<style>.insegnanti{vertical-align: bottom}</style><div class='insegnanti' id='i" + instructor[i].id + "'><img src='" + instructor[i].image + "'><div class='desc'><b><p style='font-size:20px'>" + instructor[i].name + " " + instructor[i].surname + "</b></p><br><br>" + instructor[i].description + "</div></div><div class='twitter'><a class='twitter-timeline' href='https://twitter.com/" + instructor[i].twitter + "' data-widget-id='" + instructor[i].twitter_id + "'>Tweet di @" + instructor[i].twitter + "</a></div>";
        $(".contenitore-dinamico").html(el);
        $(".contenitore-dinamico").fadeOut(1);
        $(".contenitore-dinamico").fadeIn(3000);

        !function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
            if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }
        }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");

    },
    error: function (request, error) {
        console.log("Error");
    }
});
```

where  !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https'; ... it's the script take from twitter for embed the timelines of my instructors.

My question if: everytime i click a teacher works perfectly, but when i change che instructor the script doesnt refresh (i think) and the timeline doesnt appear. How I can do? 
Thanks all!

Comment: That is some hideously formatted code you have there. Consider correcting your code formatting to improve the chance of a response.

Comment: What does "change the instructor" mean?

Comment: Try adding the following line: `$('script#twitter-wjs').remove();` Before the call to do the twitter code `!function(d,s,id)...` I am not 100% sure it will work but it should remove the script so it may pull again.

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond - removing a script tag that has already been parsed has no effect.

Comment: "change the instructor" means that i have a result via json from my database. When i click on one instructor ajax call "./query/ins_desc.php" and the code that i wrote. The twitter timeline of the instructor appear only one time: when i go back and i choose any instructor, the timeline is the only thing it doesn't load

Comment: http://hyp.altervista.org I uploaded everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following line: `$('script#twitter-wjs').remove();` Before the call to do the twitter code 
`!function(d,s,id)...`

The final result should be:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    //dataType: "json", //type of data
    crossDomain: true, //localhost purposes
    url: "./query/ins_desc.php", //Relative or absolute path to file.php file
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(response));
        var instructor = JSON.parse(response);
        var el = "";
        i = i - 1;
        el += "<style>.insegnanti{vertical-align: bottom}</style><div class='insegnanti' id='i" + instructor[i].id + "'><img src='" + instructor[i].image + "'><div class='desc'><b><p style='font-size:20px'>" + instructor[i].name + " " + instructor[i].surname + "</b></p><br><br>" + instructor[i].description + "</div></div><div class='twitter'><a class='twitter-timeline' href='https://twitter.com/" + instructor[i].twitter + "' data-widget-id='" + instructor[i].twitter_id + "'>Tweet di @" + instructor[i].twitter + "</a></div>";
        $(".contenitore-dinamico").html(el);
        $(".contenitore-dinamico").fadeOut(1);
        $(".contenitore-dinamico").fadeIn(3000);
        $('script#twitter-wjs').remove();
        !function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
            if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }
        }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");

    },
    error: function (request, error) {
        console.log("Error");
    }
});
```

I tested it locally on the site link. And set up a JSFiddle to demonstrate the code in action, obviously simulated since I don't have your php scripts. Since you pull dynamically modified code and insert the `<a>` twitter anchor tags, it will reload appropriately each time. Plus the browser is smart enough to pull the script from cache.

http://jsfiddle.net/pg7man7k/

Comment: PERFECT! I'm sorry, i didn't try it before 'cause i thought it doesnt work! Thanks again!